# Does the following code actually implement the LCG algorithm in assembly

Tags: assembly, random, x86, tasm

I heard that in the Logical Congruential Generator algorithm, we should use the previous number we generated in order to generate a new one. However, I found the following piece of code:

```
MOV     AH, 00h   ; interrupt to get system timer in CX:DX 
INT     1AH
mov     [PRN], dx
call    CalcNew   ; -> AX is a random number
xor     dx, dx
mov     cx, 10    
div     cx        ; here dx contains the remainder - from 0 to 9
add     dl, '0'   ; to ascii from '0' to '9'
mov     ah, 02h   ; call interrupt to display a value in DL
int     21h    
call    CalcNew   ; -> AX is another random number
...
ret

; ----------------
; inputs: none  (modifies PRN seed variable)
; clobbers: DX.  returns: AX = next random number
CalcNew:
    mov     ax, 25173          ; LCG Multiplier
    mul     word ptr [PRN]     ; DX:AX = LCG multiplier * seed
    add     ax, 13849          ; Add LCG increment value
    ; Modulo 65536, AX = (multiplier*seed+increment) mod 65536
    mov     [PRN], ax          ; Update seed = return value
    ret
```

and I saw that it uses the system time every time, and not the previous number. Am I right?
I am using TASM.

Answer (score 1):

The `CalcNew` function correctly uses the previous seed.  Just look at the code between the `CalcNew:` label and the `ret`.

AH=0 / `int 1AH` + `mov   [PRN], dx` seeds the LCG.
Do that once in your whole program, like in your code.

For later calls, just `call  CalcNew` (and process the result into whatever range you want).  Notice that the calling code seeds with the low bits of the current time before the first call, but makes two total calls.  It doesn't re-seed between them.